# How do I make a full loop / circuit in the railway system?

Tags: anylogic

I am aware this may seem like an obvious question, but I cannot figure it out.

Whenever I try and connect two pieces of straight track and they look connected, it still gives me the error that "there is no straight route" between the two points. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried to ensure that you get a green indication when connecting the two tracks?